# jquery animate down (100% element height)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate, slidedown

What I want to do can be accomplished just by using:

```
 slideDown("fast");
```

However, I don't like how it reveals the element, I would like for it to be 100% of the elements original height, and roll down. I'm wondering if there's an easy way of doing this? Other than perhaps changing the margin-top and such, then animating it back to normal.

Example of what I want to do:
http://jsfiddle.net/7dary/1/
However I would like to have it just do all of the calculations automatically, and it not show in the middle of the page if it's at the bottom of the page and I personally assign -200px or something to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution:

```
var $element = $("#itemToSlide"); // make sure its visible
var height = $element.height(); // get the height when its populated
$element.css({marginTop:height*-1}); // set it to 0 with an overflow hidden

// trigger the animate now or later in an event
$element.show().animate({marginTop:0},2200);
```

link: http://jsfiddle.net/MattLo/7dary/2/

Comment: Thanks, however you say it needs to be visible, well it needs to be invisible to start off with, and be pushed into view

Comment: Updated, visible might give undesirable cross browser problems.

Comment: This is the effect I'm looking for, not the one you showed an example of.
http://jsfiddle.net/7dary/1/
This works fine, however I was hoping there would be some way of doing this automatically, and not having to change the margins on my own, because 1: height will be different per instance, and 2: most of the time -200px will just have it in the middle of the page or something.

Comment: Try this updated code http://jsfiddle.net/MattLo/7dary/2/ I've updated the post too