# How do I slide down outer div while also sliding down inner contents (initially hidden)?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div containing three images.  I want to slide down the div on hover (which is working correctly).  However, while the outer div slides down, the images are not sliding down.  Instead, they are being exposed incrementally (not moving) as the outer div slides down.

How can I get the outer div to slide down and make the images slide down (moving downward) initially from their hidden position as opposed to being incrementally displayed and not moving at all?

CSS

```
div.Game {width: 100%; height: 500px; border: solid 1px}
div.options { height: 30px; position:relative; display: none; background-color: #f3f3f3; z-index: 3; width: 100% }
div.options div {display: inline-block}
div.options img {z-index: 4; max-height: 30px}
div.shadow img {max-height: 5px; width: 100%}
div.shadow {display: block !important}
div.wrapper {display: block; position: relative; width: 100%; overflow: hidden}
```

HTML

```
  <div class="Game">
        <div class="wrapper">
                 <div class="options">
                     <div style="float:left; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px"><a class="move"><img src="http://www.imagesup.net/di-3142084693010.png"/></a></div>
                <div style="float:right; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px"><a class="resize"><img src="http://www.imagesup.net/di-15142084696415.png"/></a></div>
                <div style="float:right; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px"><a class="remove"><img src="http://www.imagesup.net/di-214208466443.png"/></a></div>
                </div>
                <div class="shadow">
                <img src="http://www.imagesup.net/di-1114208466444.png" />
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

JS

```
        $("div.Game").hover(function () {
           $("div.options").slideDown("fast");
        }, function () {
            $(this).find("div.options").slideUp("fast");
        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/496c0qp7/9/

EDIT

After some searching I found an example close to what I am trying to make happen.  It uses animate instead of slide method.  I will post an updated fiddle of my provided code.

[jquery animate down (100% element height)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8959518/jquery-animate-down-100-element-height)

http://jsfiddle.net/7dary/1/

http://jsfiddle.net/MattLo/7dary/2/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I fully understand what you are asking for, but I will give it a shot.

I added a couple things to the jQuery:

```
$("div.Game").hover(function () {
    $("div.options, div.options *").slideDown("fast");
}, function () {
    $(this).find("div.options, div.options *").slideUp("fast");
});
```

Example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/bjogden/496c0qp7/10/

Like I said, I don't fully understand what you are asking for, so if this isn't right, I'll give it another go.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment and help.  The best way I can describe what I am trying to achieve is that I want all three images to be "pulled" down similar to when one rolls down paper towels.  The image is not visible initially but when I slide down the paper towel, I begin to see the image.  Again, it is somewhat of a crude example but I could not think of anything else.  Thank you.

Comment: Ah, I understand what you are asking now. Thank you for the clarity. Try testing different solutions using `.slideDown("slow", "linear");` so it is easy to see what the code/images are doing.

Comment: Have you tried using `.animate()` instead of `.slideDown()`? http://jsfiddle.net/bjogden/nyuz9/32/

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  In both cases the image(s) stays in its position as the outer div is sliding.  I was trying (unsuccessfully) to move the image with the div so that the image slides down with the div as opposed to being unveiled from the sliding div.

Comment: I found an example on www.nba.com of what I am trying to achieve.  If I hover over the bottom headlines of each of the 6 divs, the headline div slides up and the text moves up with it.  This is the effect that I am trying to create.